# Getting 403 Error While Accessing FPPlanQuotes API

Tags: healthcare-finder-api

I'm getting following error while using fpplan quotes api.

> RuntimeError: Error requesting quotes from HHS: 403   
>   Access Denied
>
> ## Access Denied
>
> You don't have permission to access
>   "http://api.finder.healthcare.gov/v3.0/getIFPPlanQuotes"
>   on this server.
>
> Reference #18.3c367c68.1478156165.473be90

I'm accessing this from out of USA., any input will be appreciated.

EDIT:
getiFPPLanQuotes Healthcare.gov Finder API XML Error - Request is not valid for the schema Screen shot.
This error is being seen from within the USA.
[image: getiFPPLanQuotes Healthcare.gov Finder API XML Error - Request is not valid for the schema Screen shot.]

Comment: @albert I have a valid schema, but I'm getting the error if permission of access.

Comment: I'm accessing this from out of US, is that the problem??

Comment: i'm not sure. i was just providing a different glimpse to help pinpoint the problem(s)